# Python: Convert array into integer

Tags: python, arrays, int

I was wondering if there is a way in Python to convert an array or a list into one single number:

A=[0xaa,0xbb,0xcc]

d=0xaabbcc

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

For Python3+, `int` has a method for this

```
>>> A=[0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc]
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(A, byteorder="big"))
'0xaabbcc'

>>> 0xaabbcc == int.from_bytes(A, byteorder="big")
True
```

For Python2, it's probably best to write a small function

```
>>> A = [0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc]
>>> 
>>> def to_hex(arr):
...     res = 0
...     for i in arr:
...         res <<= 8
...         res += i
...     return res
... 
>>> 0xaabbcc == to_hex(A)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `hex()`, `map()`, and `join()`.

```
>>> '0x' + ''.join(map(hex, A)).replace('0x', '')
'0xaabbcc'
```

Or with `lambda`:

```
>>> '0x' + ''.join(map(lambda x: hex(x)[2:], A))
'0xaabbcc'
```

Thanks to @John La Rooy for pointing out that this fails with 1-digit numbers. The following modification of the `lambda` version is better:

```
>>> B = [0x1, 0x4, 0x3]
>>> '0x' + ''.join(map(lambda x: hex(x)[2:].rjust(2, '0'), B))
'0x010403'
```

But at that point it's better to use John's answer.

Comment: What if some elements of A  are < 0x10?

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc]
d = reduce(lambda x, y: x*256 + y, A)
print hex(d)
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `x << y.bit_length()` instead of `x*256` to make your code more flexible

Comment: @Alik You are right, but only if the original question wants to deal with bits instead of bytes. Please note that for `a = 1` the `a.bit_length()` gives 1.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about the question this way. I think OP should clarify what he wants to do.